# Keep formatting of Graphics.drawString into a String object (Java)

Tags: java, graphics

I have some code rendering a page with complex formatting and preparing it for print.
The code looks something like this:

```
 graphics.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 10));
 final FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics();
 final int cw = fontMetrics.charWidth('M');
 int y = fontMetrics.getAscent();

 graphics.drawString("Page: " + (pageIndex + 1), 68*cw, y);
 ...
```

What I would like is to have also this text into a String. I was thinking about putting it into a StringBuilder and append it every time I draw something. However, this does not keep the formatting (because of the fact, like in the example above, I put stuff on different places on the document).

Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking.  `"Page: " + (pageIndex + 1)` is already a String.  How would you use a String to retain formatting?  Can you include in your question an example of how you are thinking of using StringBuilder?

Comment: I could use, for example sb.append("Page: x");, but the current implementation (the one with Graphics) will add the text, at 68 characters from the left hand side..
If I use append, this formatting will be gone and the text will be placed on the beginning of the row.
Do you understand what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I still do not understand.  What would `sb` contain prior to executing `sb.append("Page: x")`?  The text is positioned according to the x coordinate you pass to `drawString`, so how will using a String or StringBuilder change that?

Comment: Ok, I see what you are missing. I need as an output of this, both the graphics object, but in addition I also need a String which will contain the formatted result. Therefore, the code should be like: `graphics.drawString("Page: 3", 68*cw, y);
sb.append("Page: 3");`. In the first case, the text will be put at 68's "position", in the second case, will be in the first "position"

Comment: A string cannot contain positional formatting.  You will need to create a class which holds, at the very least, the text and the text's position.

Comment: I know that it doesn't, that's why I asked for help in finding an alternate solution. I think I will append as many spaces as pixels are in the drawString, to the string builder and live with that.. Even though is not a nice solution

Comment: If you need to retain formatting information, what's wrong with creating a class to hold it?